# Why is Opencv/Hough Transform not finding the whole line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I finished a tutorial on OpenCv for finding lanes, and I am trying to apply it to finding a piece of tape on the floor. I got the code running and set the region of interest but it only finds a few edges of the tape. I think it has to do with the thickness but I am not 100% sure. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image: Track]
[image: Track 2]
[image: Track 3]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def canny(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 10)
    return line_image

def region_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([
        [(200, height), (400, height), (355, 0)]
        ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
    return masked_image

image = cv2.imread('tape3.jpg')
lane_image = np.copy(image)
canny_image = canny(image)
cropped_image = region_of_interest(canny_image)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
line_image = display_lines(lane_image, lines)
combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(lane_image, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
# cv2 print image
print(region_of_interest(image))
cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Is the lane always going to be black tape?  With the region of interest, couldn't you do some simple colour analysis + thresholding to find where the tape is?

Comment: Eventually, it is going to be black tape with red strips on it(red strips are horizontal) so I don't really know if thresholding would work well for that.

Comment: Hough lines uses Canny edge detector. Check if the canny image correctly finds the edge on the whole tape. The tape is not completely straight, so you won't be able to detect the whole border as a single line segment. You will have to fine tune thresholds and parameters to get the correct result.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I will update the code to include the canny function I used.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Please update your post to provide sample images for the beginning, middle and end of the track.  One image is not enough to convince us that what we propose will work.

Comment: @rayryeng you want three separate images of the track?

Comment: Yes that'd be great.  I'd love to see all of the scenarios you're targetting to make sure that what we provide will work for your use case.  Just the one wouldn't be enough, especially if there is red horizontal tape.  Also since the tape is curved, I would not use the Hough Transform.  Consider using `cv2.findContours`.

Comment: @rayryeng actually, it was not supposed to be like that. It is supposed to be straight and for corners it will be a 90 degree angle. But if we could detect the horizontal markers using black tape that would work great, though it would be difficult telling turns and markers apart

Comment: I would still use `cv2.findContours` because you may not get the alignment of the tape to be 100% perfect.  Also there may be some slight barrel distortion of your camera when you image the track.  I'm assuming that you won't be using a high-res camera to capture the track like the one you used above?  I'm assuming you want to use a camera that's mounted on some microcontroller.

Comment: @rayryeng I haven't decided about Camera, though I think that just mounting a low res web cam(prob. 480p) would be the easiest way to do it. Is there a better way we could have this conversation because while your help is incredible, email/discord would be a lot easier.

Comment: @rayryeng am uploading the new pictures, they will be there in one second

Comment: @rayryeng I added the other pictures including the turn, a stretch of just track and a stretch a horizontal marker.

Comment: have you tried thresholding for the color of the tape and then using findContours? That's typically how I handle this sort of thing though that depends on what you want to do with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not answer your original question, but this could be an alternate way to achieve what you're looking for.

I started by thresholding the grayscale of the image to try and isolate the tape

[image]

Then I used opencv's findContours to get the segmentation points of each white blob

[image]

The thresholding method I used is sensitive to light and shadow so you may have to find some other thresholding method if this isn't a workable constraint. If different colored tape is a concern, you can threshold off of other values (convert to HSV or LAB and threshold off of the H or B channels respectively to look for red).

Edit:

If you still want to use HoughLinesP, here's a working example with your picture.

First I applied canny:

[image]

Then I used the HoughLinesP function:

[image]

I've never used houghLinesP before so I'm not sure of the potential pitfalls, but it seems to work, though it actually creates a bunch of overlapping lines with these parameters, you'll have to play around with it a bit.

Relevant Code:

```py
# canny
canned = cv2.Canny(gray, 591, 269);

# dilate
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);
canned = cv2.dilate(canned, kernel, iterations = 1);

# hough
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canned, rho = 1, theta = 1*np.pi/180, threshold = 30, minLineLength = 10, maxLineGap = 20);
```

Edit 2:

I looked at the documentation for the function and the third parameter (theta) refers to the angle resolution. I think it might not have worked in your code because you didn't run dilation on the image after Canny. With a one-degree search resolution it's not hard to imagine that we could miss the very thin line that canny returns. It might even be worth dilating the lines more than I did in the example by using a larger kernel (or dilating multiple times).